# Word - document object code reference

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document on which I have created a checkbox from the Control Toolkit.  I have added a text box to the word document that I want visible only when the check box is clicked.  I have the code I need to make the text box visible based on the checkmark from another similar piece of code.
What I need is the name of the text box that I put on the document so I can refer to it in my code...the other text box is 27, do I just need to try incrementing numbers until I get lucky or is there some method to the madness where I can look to see what the number is?

```
Private Sub OtherChk_Click()
    If OtherChk = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box ??").Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoTrue
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box ??").Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoFalse
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: in order to move along i just started plugging in numbers until i found the right one, hopefully someone knows the proper way to find the object name.

Answer (score 1):

Since with word you can be talking about Content controls, Form fields or Older style activex controls, each of which have their own quirks, it's tough to answer a question like this directly.

For instance, I created a new word doc (word 2010), clicked the developer tab and dropped down the "control toolbar" button in the ribbon, there's "Legacy forms" and "activex controls" listed,

I clicked the DESIGN MODE button, then chose the Textbox activex control, dropped on on the form, right clicked it and selected "Properties"

that pops up the VERY old school looking properties browser (I don't think that code has been touched in word in years), but, at the top, you have the controlname, defaulted to TextBox1

You can change that name to whatever you want, and then reference the control via that name.

You MAY need to do a for-next through all the controls checking the NAME property (I'm not sure off hand if the indexed collection will index on name or just on the index number).

Comment: +1, good answer. sounds like she's talking about old school activex controls.

Comment: the text box that i am referring to came from the drawing toolbar...just a regular old text box!